# Android app can't find resources on device, works on simulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android app that has been working for some time now.  Recently I noticed that there was a 'res' subdirectory under the 'assets' directory and I deleted it from the project.  There was, and always has been, a res directory at the project level (at the same level as 'src', 'libs', 'assets', etc.  And all of the correct resource files are in there (drawables, xml layouts, a string table, etc.).

When I build and run the project on a simulator it runs fine.  When I build and run on a device the app can't find any resources.  The app crashes the first time it tries to reference a resource ("setContentView(R.layout.startup);").

I've verified that R.layout.startup refers to to "myprojectname.R.layout" namespace.  In the 'gen' directory there is a R.java in the "com.mycompany.myprojectname" namespace and I can expand that object all the way down to the 'startup' reference.

Again, it runs on the simulator, not on the several devices that I've tried.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working again?

Comment: Did you try deleting your /bin directory?

Comment: Tried deleting the /bin directory.  No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have several alternate layout directories? res/layout-land etc?
In that case, maybe your app is trying to load the layout from an alternate directory you don't have anything in.

Comment: No there is no alternate layout directory for this resource.  Actually, I believe that none of the resources for the package are accessible.  The icon doesn't even show on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? I've had some of my resource references get screwy and this fixed it in the past for me.

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding.  No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Which android.R are the java files importing? You might want to check the location they are pointing to.